# SQL query (using microsoft access) using "Like" statement doesnt work

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

im trying to get all fields in Customers table that the Company Name either starts with an 'A' or ends with an 'e'

for some reason this query returns empty fields (i do have company names starts with an A or ends with an e)

```
SELECT Customers.*
FROM Customers
WHERE 'Customers.Company Name' 
LIKE 'A*' OR LIKE '*e';
```

now when i thought there was a problem with the syntax i tried this:

```
SELECT Customers.*
FROM Customers
WHERE 'Customers.Company Name' 
LIKE 'A*';
```

also doesnt work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify what Gordon said, you must not have quotes round the Customers.CustomerName part. If you have a space in your table or field name (a bad practice) you must instead use [].

Also to do an OR filter you must repeat the left-hand side, i.e.

```
WHERE Customers.[Company Name] LIKE 'A*' OR Customers.[Company Name] LIKE '*e';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your quotes correct.  In MS Access, this would be:

```
SELECT Customers.*
FROM Customers
WHERE Customers.Company Name LIKE "A*";
```

Comment: the query seems to work but still im getting empty fields, so my guess its not the syntax, any ideas?

Comment: @DoronTorangy . . . No company names start with "A".

Comment: i do have 4 companies with starts with an A. for some reason even simple queries like SELECT returns empty recordset. maybe a problem in MS Access? cause i copied the same query to mySql and it worked

Comment: @DoronTorangy . . . The queries in your question are not syntactically correct.  If you made the obvious fixes (fixing the quotes), they sill wouldn't work (`and like` is not valid SQL syntax).  Even if you fixed all that, `*` is not a wildcard in MySQL.  You may want to try the ANSI standard wildcard, `%` to see if that works.

Comment: Per @GordonLinoff's last comment, how are you connecting to MS Access: from the GUI .exe Office app or as a backend database via odbc? This matters as the former uses the asterisk, `*`, wildcard by default and latter only uses ANSI `%`. See [docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what Gordon and Mark said, [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=access%20sql%20where%20clause%20condition%20syntax) is a sample Google search you'd want to check out, to become more familiar with SQL syntax with the help of pages like [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Access-SQL-d5f21d10-cd73-4507-925e-bb26e377fe7e?CorrelationId=9f4e58cb-e43c-4c46-ab6c-cf27ea8c6b9c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010341468#bm2) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp).